# How to insert (array) data into a PostgreSQL bytea column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, bytea

How can I store the following data structure:

```
byte[] number = new byte[1000];
```

in **bytea** column in PostgreSQL with

INSERT INTO blobT command?

```
 CREATE TABLE blobT (
    blob      bytea
 );
```

What is the equivalence of **bytea** in MySQL and Microsoft SQL?

Comment: you can use blob in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

For MySql you can do

```
 CREATE TABLE blobT (
    bytea blob;     
 );


String query = "INSERT INTO blobT (bytea) VALUES (?)"; 
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setBytes(1, bytea);
pstmt.execute();
```

Comment: How would you store bytea in Java?

Comment: luksmir, I think bytea is escaped by the jdbc driver, so you should just be able to do a standard parameterized query, with the appropriate variable binding.